# Производительность компьютера

Tags: c, c++

Как узнать время работы C++ программы в флопсах?

Comment: Флопсы измеряют не время рАботы, а производительность компьютера. А узнать можно с помощью специальных тестов.

Comment: ага, понятно. спосибо

Comment: а как подсчитать точное время работы алгоритма ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы подсчитать время выполнения фрагмента кода, можно использовать функции из хедера time.h:

time_t time(time_t*) - возвращает стандартное текущее время в секундах. Низкое разрешение - до секунды.

clock_t clock() - возвращает количество тактов процессора с момента начала работы процесса. Для пересчета в секунды применяем формулу  clock () / CLOCKS_PER_SEC.  CLOCKS_PER_SEC - константа, определенная в time.h

Алгоритм замера простой:

```
определяем время t1 до начала нужного фрагмента
////  код
определяем время t2 после нужного фрагмента

delta_time = t2 - t1
```

Comment: Еще gettimeofday (man 2 gettimeofday). Но микросекундам верить нельзя.

Comment: во-во - верить нельзя

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <intrin.h>
#pragma intrinsic(__rdtsc)
```

и

```
unsigned int before  = __rdtsc();

// Что-то делаем ...

unsigned int after = __rdtsc();

// Время выполнения
unsigned int ticks = after - before;
```

P.S. Может выдавать неверные значения на многоядерных/многопроцессорных системах.

Comment: \_\_rdtsc() это какая ОС и какие библиотеки надо подключать ? У меня (Windows 7 MinGW) не нашлась.

Comment: Обновил для Visual C++.

Comment: А вот здесь способ использования в никсах на gcc: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rdtsc

Answer (score 0):

Ещё можно замерять производительность при помощи QueryPerformanceCounter и QueryPerformanceFrequency. Только это работает только на Windows. QueryPerformanceCounter показывает время в тактах. Ты их имел в виду, когда писал "в флопсах"? Чтобы узнать время, нужно разделить это число на частоту, которую можно узнать при помощи QueryPerformanceFrequency.

Для точного замера времени нужно повторить выполнение кода в цикле много раз и разделить это время на количество раз. Одну быструю команду ты точно не замеришь, потому что будут некоторые погрешности из-за накладных расходов на работу таймера.